# Errno 111 Connection refused from web.archive.org

Tags: python

Does web.archive.org have any limits?

I'm trying to pump pages out of webarchive with pause using python. But after less than a minute I get an error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last) NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ae32e962fe0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last) MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='web.archive.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /web/20230331062349/http://100vann.ru/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ae32e962fe0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last) /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    517                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    518 
--> 519             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    520 
    521         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='web.archive.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /web/20230331062349/http://100vann.ru/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ae32e962fe0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I try to open by this code:

```
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
  time.sleep(1)
  headers.update(
    {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    }
  )
  webarchive = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=15)
  webarchive.raise_for_status()

  if webarchive.status_code == 200:
```

How do services pump out a site of several thousand pages? If you put large pauses, it takes forever. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What "services"? And anyway, you wouldn't get a connection refused if you were being throttled, it's just a transient issue...

Comment: You may want to look at https://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php anyway.

Comment: Respect the limits put in place by a service provider. It's not reasonable to expect to consume all of a site's content to the detriment of users who actually want to use the site for its intended purpose. i.e. if I can't use the internet archive because you're currently spamming it with a crawler I will not be happy. And yes, if an API is available then use it

Answer (score 1):

The rate limit for the Internet Archive / Wayback Machine is no more than 15 requests per minute.  This limit has been in place since November 2019 according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine#Technical_information).

See also: https://archive.org/details/toomanyrequests_20191110

---

> What am I doing wrong?

Presumably you are exceeding the 15 requests per minute limit, and that is resulting in the service refusing your connections for a period.

If you wish to discuss this with the people who run the service, the above link includes a contact email for asking questions.

Now you could attempt work around the rate limits, but if you did that the people who run the service may decide to block your access entirely.  I'm sure they have technical ways to "drop the hammer" on you.

If you read the Internet Archive's T&Cs, they reserve the right to terminate their agreement with you.